# Rate-limiting & dropping natted packets, EXCEPT for 5 local networks

Tags: linux, iptables, nat

Basically, I am trying to rate-limit requests to a mailserver at the firewall level, but whitelist several company-owned IP ranges.  I can whitelist *one* IP addresses range, but not several, because of the nature of "first matching rule takes the packet."

Here is what I have currently... (sorry for the mix of `-I` and `-A`)

```
# Send traffic to rate-limiter before allowing it to continue to the mail server.
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 20.87.6.71 -p tcp --destination-port 25 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.250.71:25
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 20.87.6.71 -p tcp --destination-port 143 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.250.71:143
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 20.87.6.71 -p tcp --destination-port 993 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.250.71:993
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -d 20.87.6.71 -p tcp --destination-port 25 -j rate-limiter
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -d 20.87.6.71 -p tcp --destination-port 143 -j rate-limiter
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -d 20.87.6.71 -p tcp --destination-port 993 -j rate-limiter

# Create a new chain, which logs all traffic then drops it.
# We make sure that localnets are not part of this...
iptables -t mangle -N rate-limiter
iptables -t mangle -A rate-limiter -p tcp --syn -d 20.87.6.71 ! -s 192.168.254.0/24 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name MailRateLimiter --rsource
iptables -t mangle -A rate-limiter -p tcp --syn -d 20.87.6.71 ! -s 20.87.6.0/24 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name MailRateLimiter --rsource

iptables -t mangle -A rate-limiter -p tcp --syn -d 20.87.6.71 ! -s 192.168.250.0/24 -m state --state NEW -m recent --rcheck --seconds 60 --hitcount 20 --name MailRateLimiter --rsource -j LOG --log-prefix 'RATE EXCEEDED' --log-level 4
iptables -t mangle -A rate-limiter -p tcp --syn -d 20.87.6.71 ! -s 192.168.250.0/24 -m state --state NEW -m recent --rcheck --seconds 60 --hitcount 20 --name MailRateLimiter --rsource -j DROP

iptables -t mangle -A rate-limiter -p tcp --syn -d 20.87.6.71 ! -s 20.87.6.0/24 -m state --state NEW -m recent --rcheck --seconds 60 --hitcount 20 --name MailRateLimiter --rsource -j LOG --log-prefix 'RATE EXCEEDED' --log-level 4
iptables -t mangle -A rate-limiter -p tcp --syn -d 20.87.6.71 ! -s 20.87.6.0/24 -m state --state NEW -m recent --rcheck --seconds 60 --hitcount 20 --name MailRateLimiter --rsource -j DROP
```

So, the first rule matches the packet, then marks it in the recent table, so when I `cat /proc/self/net/xt_recent/MailRateLimiter`, I see IPs that should be whitelisted:

```
src=20.87.6.200 ttl: 57 last_seen: 56654988107 oldest_pkt: 8 56654320106, 56654370481, 56654426548, 56654480458, 56654564349, 56654565421, 56654952936, 56654988107
src=20.87.6.5 ttl: 63 last_seen: 56655077970 oldest_pkt: 9 56654962465, 56654962465, 56654978465, 56655024835, 56655031038, 56655037096, 56655048206, 56655059305, 56655077970, 56654768325, 56654777150, 56654802008, 56654807677, 56654816481, 56654842497, 56654846996, 56654855809, 56654886875, 5665489136
```

Forgive me if it is something stupid... It has been a long day, and I kind of got thrown into this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can whitelist anything you want writing the following at the top of the CHAIN:

`iptables -t mangle -A rate-limiter <rule to match whitelisted> -j RETURN`

Packets matching the whitelisted networks will return to `POSTROUTING` without modification.

Comment: THANK YOU!  I didn't know you could do that!  Worked perfectly.